# REST API design for messages

Tags: api, rest, message

I have two type of users on the site: simple users (Clients) and professional users (Performers).

Performers can be included into the third entity type - Teams.

Client can

- Client can write to a Client.
- Client can write to a Performer.
- Client can write to a Team.

Respectively Performer can

- Performer can write to a Client.
- Performer can write to a Performer.
- Performer can write to a Team.

What API paths can you suggest to handle messaging flow taking into account the following specifically:

1) Client and Performer should be able to write messages each other and to Teams.

2) Client and Performer should be able to get list of "chats" they are participating.

What are best practices to make this flow RESTful?

**UPD.**

### Tables

I'll try to be more specific - I have these tables:

- `client`

  - stores all client's data (`client_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, etc)
- `performer`

  - stores all performer's data (`performer_id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `service_area_title`,  etc)
- `team`

  - holds just team's title and some meta-data, e.g. performers_count
- `teams_performers`

  - `team_id`, `performer_id`
  - for NxM relationship

As for `messages`, the following tables exist:

- `message`

  - `message_id`, `message`, `owner_id`, `owner_type`, `created_at`
  - owner_type is ENUM and can be either `client`, or `performer`
- `chat`

  - `chat_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`
  - `updated_at` is the same as created_at of the last message in the chat
- `chats_participants`

  - `chat_id`, `participant_id`, `participant_type`
- `chat_messages`

  - `chat_id`, `message_id`

### API

Basic api url is as follows: `api.site.com/v1/`

Clients, performers and teams can be treated as resources, i.e. I have already methods like:

- creation of client

  `POST api.site.com/v1/clients`
- updating of performer

  `PATCH api.site.com/v1/performers/:performerId`
- getting of the teams where performer participating

  `GET api.site.com/v1/performers/:performerId/teams`
- remove performer from a team

  `DELETE api.site.com/v1/teams/:teamId/performers/:performerId`

Comment: You are basically asking us to design your project for you, that's a bit too much to ask here. 'API paths' should be based on how your models are related to eachother etc, and since you haven't defined that, we can't suggest any 'API paths'.

Comment: Thank you, Tim. I've updated description for more clarity.

Comment: Ok, so what's the question now? Have you already solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Lets try and answer your real question

> What are best practices to make this flow RESTful?

I would suggest you start with some reading, the [Richardson maturity model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) would be a good start.

It outlines 4 `levels` to achieve an restful api, these are good principles as a starting point, for a high level understanding.

- Level 0 - Not restful (standard rpc)
- Level 1 - Using individual Resources
- Level 2 - Using HTTP Verbs (get, delete, post etc.)
- Level 3 - And finally Hypermedia Controls

The nest place I would go is, http://restcookbook.com, which fills in the blanks in more implementation specific questions.

Now with all the knowledge you have gained, you should easily be able to design your Apis.